# Basic Python price scraper for Amazon

Tags: python

I am new to Python but attempting to build a simple price scraper that takes a list of ASINs from a spreadsheet, checks the price on Amazon and then adds that price into the next column. It will color code it if the two prices do not match.

```
import requests
import openpyxl
import time
from datetime import datetime
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# User agent for the requests
user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/116.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"

# Load the Excel file
excel_file = 'products_demo.xlsx'
workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(excel_file)
sheet = workbook.active

# Get the number of rows in the sheet
num_rows = sheet.max_row

# Set the first row of column C with the current date and time
sheet['C1'] = 'Price as of ' + datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

# Loop through ASINs and scrape prices
for row in range(2, num_rows + 1):
    asin = sheet.cell(row=row, column=1).value
    url = f"https://www.amazon.com/dp/{asin}"
    
    headers = {
        'User-Agent': user_agent
    }
    
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    print(response)
    
    # Print response code in column D
    sheet.cell(row=row, column=4, value=response.status_code)
    
    if response.status_code == 200:
        # Find the <span> with class "a-offscreen"
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
        price_element = soup.find('span', {'class': 'a-offscreen'})
        print(price_element)
        
        if price_element:
            current_price = price_element.get_text().strip()
            sheet.cell(row=row, column=3, value=current_price)
            
            # Compare with the previous price in column B and highlight if different
            previous_price = sheet.cell(row=row, column=2).value
            if previous_price != current_price:
                sheet.cell(row=row, column=3).fill = openpyxl.styles.PatternFill(start_color='FFFF00', end_color='FFFF00', fill_type='solid')
    else:
        print(f"Error: Unable to fetch data for ASIN {asin}")
    
    # Save the changes and wait for 5 seconds before the next request
    workbook.save('products_demo_updated.xlsx')
    time.sleep(5)

print("Scraping complete.")
```

Current code runs, very rarely does it return a value for price_element, but occasionally it does. When it returns a value it prints it to the spreedsheet and color codes correctly. But, it is 99% unreliable.

Print(price_element) is present so I can check the code while it is running in an attempt to trouble shoot.

I've attached the sheet I'm working on, as well as a screen shot of the results.

Spreadsheet to pull ASINs from: https://file.io/umB6zvWGlT9l
Spreadsheet after running Python script: https://file.io/YCrKkxSiWY7M

https://imgur.com/a/3qNps6q

Thank you!

Comment: It rarely returns the price, but occasionally does. How can I get it to return the price for each item every time?

Comment: What happens when it does not return the price? Do you mean that the status code is not 200 in that case?

Comment: It returns nothing,  print(price_element) returns "None"

Comment: This screen shot shows the occasional return of the price span, but mostly just none. https://imgur.com/a/3qNps6q

Comment: It always returns a 200 status code. I added it to print in the output to confirm.

Comment: Just because the page returns the code **200** doesn't mean the data you want to scrape is available. Can you print the **response.text** to confirm?